# Could someone point out a strategy to recreate this flowing lines animation?

Tags: workflow

I am relatively new to blender and am constantly looking for interesting new projects. I came across this video by Vitaly Grossmann working with Vizio to create an ad for their new sound system. I am completely stumped as to how he managed to create the flowing lines in the scene and would love to know how to go about something like this in Blender.

Could someone please provide a general flow of how to achieve this effect? All efforts are much appreciated!

Video link : https://vimeo.com/347370066

Comment: Probably using Animation Nodes. For instance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCghhlMOwRg.

Comment: Hi lemon,Thanks so much for this. Haven't explored animation nodes at all yet, so looking forward to it!